# create a json object from a string which contains keys and values

Tags: arrays, json

I have such strings which I get by manipulating the DOM. how can I convert them to javascript objects, so that I can later stringify them? please advise.

can I use JSON.parse with reviver?

```
str = "age: 65,  name: "Jay",  smoker: false"
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from beginning:

Your string has invalid json syntax: `"age: 65,  name: "Jay",  smoker: false"`

This is a valid json syntax: `{"age": 65, "name": "Jay", "smoker": false}`

After turn this valid, you could do just a simple parse:

`var json = JSON.parse({"age": 65, "name": "Jay", "smoker": false});`

However, do you need to convert your invalid string to a valid JS Object, right?

We can achieve it in that way:

1. Firstly, your string need to be escaped:

```js
var str = "age: 65,  name: \"Jay\",  smoker: false";
```

2. Then, apply this split-map function:

`str = str.split(',').map((str) => str.trim().substring(0, str.length).replace(': ', ':'));`

3. Finally, a loop to create the object, filtering unwanted prop types:

```js
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  var split = str[i].split(':');

  // "boolean" to boolean
  split[1] = split[1] === "true" ? true : split[1] === "false" ? false : split[1];

  // ""string"" to "string"
  split[1] = typeof split[1] === 'string' ? split[1].replace(/['"]+/g, '') : split[1];
    obj[split[0]] = split[1];
}

// results valid obj: { age: "6", name: "Jay", smoker: false }
```

Using this object, you can easily do `JSON.stringify(obj)` to get a valid json.

Of course, if you change your string structure, this functions will need re-work.

Comment: thanks, a silly question, perhaps: I will be getting many such records, how do I escape them?

Comment: Can you declare var using single quote? str = 'age: 65,  name: "Jay",  smoker: false'. This would solve the escape requirement.

Comment: hi, just one small note -str = str.split(',').map((str) => str.trim().substring(0, str.length-1).replace(': ', ':'));         just this should change: substring(0, str.length)